# Wordpress comments without depth

Tags: wordpress, function, comments

I convert a HTML template to wordpress theme and I've a trouble.
I just want to add some right padding to reply comments.
The wp_list_comments() function add child comments into a div with parent comment.

Wordpress function output:

```
<div>
  <div class="comment-1"> // comment 1
    <div class="comment-2"></div> // reply 1
    <div class="comment-3"></div> // reply 2
  </div>
  <div class="comment-4"> // comment 2
</div>
```

What I need for my template is:

```
<div>
  <div class="comment-1"></div> // comment 1
    <div class="comment-2" class="reply"></div> // reply 1
    <div class="comment-3" class="reply"></div> // reply 2
  <div class="comment-4"> // comment 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customise the comments loop using `comments.php` in your theme. The code is somewhat extensive requiring use of your `functions.php` file.

Check out this [WP Tuts article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/customizing-comments-in-wordpress-functionality-and-appearance/) on making use of the files to override the default output.